# Sequelizejs: no auto-generation of methods from associations

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, feathers-sequelize

I am trying to setup a m:n association using feathersjs with sequelize. I am following this ['instruction'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUEhRlKxrOQ), but have to adjust to updates feathersjs has gone throught in the meantime.

My hook to associate an already created user with an already created item:

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) { 
  return function (hook) {
    hook.app.service('users')
      .get(hook.data[0].user_id)
      .then(users => {
        hook.app.service('items')
          .find(hook.data[0].item_id)
          .then(benches => items.addMyusers(users));
      });

    return Promise.resolve(hook);
  };
};
```

I get:

```
error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMyusers' of undefined
```

Under my user model definition I set the asssocation with:

```
  users.associate = function (models) {
    users.belongsToMany(models.items, {
      through: {
        model: 'favorites-items',
        unique: false
      },
      foreignKey: 'item_id',
      as: 'myitems',
      constraints: false
    });
  };
```

under item model definition:

```
  items.associate = function (models) { 
    items.belongsToMany(models.users, {
      through: {
        model: 'favorites-items',
        unique: false
      },
      as: 'myusers',
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      constraints: false
    });
  };
```

Why does addMyusers not exist? Methods like these should be auto-generated when making the association?

As stated in the [sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html):

> This will add methods getUsers, setUsers, addUser,addUsers to Project,
>   and getProjects, setProjects, addProject, and addProjects to User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue related to sequelize at all.

Look at your error message carefully:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMyusers' of undefined

It's not that sequelize didn't add the method, it's that your variable `items` is undefined, and of course `undefined` does not have a `addMyusers` method. From the code you posted, `items` is not set anywhere in your code, so it is indeed undefined.